# Strange NULL safety behaviour in if statements

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am new to Dart null safety but I hack more than 20 years in languages like C/C++, C#, Java and some more.

From my Flutter app I call REST APIs on a server that was written in C# and runs in a Docker container. The object returned by the REST API has a Dart DTO which was generated by a code generator. This generator declares all members as nullable. Here is a sample:

```
class BscGetCreditCardListResponse implements IConvertible
{
    List<BscCreditCard>? creditCardList;
    ResponseStatus? responseStatus;

    BscGetCreditCardListResponse({this.creditCardList,this.responseStatus});
    BscGetCreditCardListResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) { fromMap(json); }

    fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        creditCardList = JsonConverters.fromJson(json['creditCardList'],'List<BscCreditCard>',context!);
        responseStatus = JsonConverters.fromJson(json['responseStatus'],'ResponseStatus',context!);
        return this;
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'creditCardList': JsonConverters.toJson(creditCardList,'List<BscCreditCard>',context!),
        'responseStatus': JsonConverters.toJson(responseStatus,'ResponseStatus',context!)
    };

    getTypeName() => "BscGetCreditCardListResponse";
    TypeContext? context = _ctx;
}
```

When I like to use the `creditCardList` inside the `response` object I have to write in Dart:

```
    if (response != null &&
        response.creditCardList != null &&
        response.creditCardList!.length > 0) {
      // do something here...
    }
```

Why must I write in the *last if condition* **`response.creditCardList!.length > 0`** ?? If I write `response.creditCardList.length > 0` (**NO ! after `creditCardList`**) the compiler gives me an error saying `creditCardList` could potentially be null. In my opinion this **is NOT true** since my second if condition is `response.creditCardList != null` and therefore tests for `null`. In C# for example it would NEVER reach `response.creditCardList!.length > 0` if the result of `response.creditCardList != null` is `false`.

And if I follow this logic, why does the compiler accept `response.creditCardList != null` and does **not** require `response!.creditCardList != null`.

Could anybody please explain how this works?

Comment: see if my answer here helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69090778/why-are-dart-null-safety-problems-showing-up-inconsistently-in-2-places/69091260#69091260

Comment: I get your point in kotlin nullsafty works the same as C#. Initially I'm also wonder why this show error. If you found an answer let me know too.

Comment: Even though you already checked `response.creditCardList != null`, in Dart, `response.creditCardList` is equivalent to calling a getter function, and there is no guarantee that `response.creditCardList` will continue returning a non-`null` value when accessed again.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035574/